# How should Mockito be used during JUnit4 Testing

Tags: android, kotlin, junit, mockito

I'm trying to test my use case through Mockito, but it doens't seem to work very well.
This is my use case that I wanna test:

```
class GetStudentsUseCase @Inject constructor(private val studentRepository: StudentRepository) {
    suspend fun execute():Result<List<Student>> = studentRepository.getStudents()
}
```

Then, I created GetStudentsUseCaseTest that looks like this:

```
class GetStudentsUseCaseTest {

    private lateinit var cut: GetStudentsUseCase
    private var reservationList = listOf(
        Student("Max", "122d"),
        Student("Steven", "012s")
    )

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        val fakeStudentRepository = Mockito.mock(StudentRepository::class.java)
        cut = GetStudentsUseCase(fakeStudentRepository)
    }

    @Test
    suspend fun test_name() {
        Mockito.`when`(cut.execute()).thenReturn(Result.success(reservationList))
    }
}
```

What should I put inside the test_name method?

Edit: answer with solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
class GetStudentsUseCaseTest {

    private lateinit var cut: GetStudentsUseCase
    @Mock
    private lateinit var repository: StudentRepository
    private var reservationList = listOf(
        Student("Max", "122d"),
        Student("Steven", "012s")
    )

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
        cut = GetStudentsUseCase(repository)
    }

    @Test
    fun test_name() = runTest {
        Mockito.`when`(repository.getStudents()).thenReturn(Result.success(reservationList))
        val result = cut.execute()
        assertEquals(result, Result.success(reservationList))
    }
}
```